# Can someone show me a more efficient/shorter way to write this python random # program?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python and I am eager to learn a shorter way of writing a random number program I made.

```
import random

a = random.randint(1,100)

for x in range(5):
  num = int(input("Guess my random number:\n"))
  if(num < a):
    print("Your guess is too small!")
    continue
  elif(num > a):
    print("Your guess is too big!")
    continue
  else:
    print("You got it!")
    break
  if (num == a):
    print("Hooray!")
  else:
    print("You ran out of guesses!")
print("The random number was:", a)
print("Your last guess was:", num)
print("It took you this many tries:", x+1)
```

Comment: I would reccomend going to the codereview stackexchange, as SO isnt for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Also, fix your indentation.

Comment: The `if..else` is entirely superfluous and unreachable…!?

Comment: i think its because of the indentation, its supposed to be outside the loop

Comment: Indentation aside, I say this code is actually pretty clean and readable. You could compress it via ternary operator or other tricks, but I think it's okay

Comment: Well, now that I think about it, a should have a more meaningful name. but definetely, head to CodeReview for this kind of issues!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

a = random.randint(1,100)

for x in range(5):
    num = int(input("Guess my random number:\n"))
    if num < a:
        print("Your guess is too small!")
    elif num > a:
        print("Your guess is too big!")
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        print("Hooray!")
        break
else:
    print("You ran out of guesses!")

print(f"The random number was: {a}")
print(f"Your last guess was: {num}")
print(f"It took you {x+1} tries.")
```

For loop in python supports `else` keyword. The code after `else` is executed, if loop is exited normally (without `break`). Your 'Hoorray!' is printed only right after 'You got it!' or not printed at all, so they can be merged.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris_Rands mentions, the code is overall ok (except for the indentation, which I assume is an error when pasting. The continues are not needed though, and the extra parenthesis either.

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 100)

for x in range(5):
    num = int(input("Guess my random number:\n"))
    if num != a:
        print("Your guess is too %s!" % 'small' if num < a else 'big')
    else:
        print("You got it!\nHooray!")
        break
else:
    print("You ran out of guesses!")

print("The random number was:", a)
print("Your last guess was:", num)
print("It took you %s many tries" % x+1)
```